# Regex: Slack-like 'markdown' for matching exactly one formatting character

Tags: javascript, regex, formatting, markdown

I've tried researching this but could only figure out how to make my search terms so precise.

I want the user to be able to surround text with symbols, `_`, `*`, `~`, etc. for markdown-like formatting, basically the way Slack does it. I got it working pretty well, but I have one issue.

When the user types `_bold_`, I render `<strong>bold</strong>`, which is the desired effect. But when the user types `__bold__`, I get `<strong>_bold_</strong>` when I would rather just get `__bold__`.

Here's my regex:

```
const rules = [
    {regex: /_{1}(.+?)_{1}/g, replacement: '<em>$1</em>'},
    {regex: /\*{1}(.+?)\*{1}/g, replacement: '<strong>$1</strong>'},
    // etc
];
```

Then I'm running:

```
let formattedText = '__some text__'; // the user input
rules.forEach(rule => formattedText = formattedText.replace(rule.regex, rule.replacement));
```

It matches only the one with `{1}`. But how do I make it ignore cases where there are multiple?

Comment: Try `{regex: /(^|[^_])_(?!_)((?:.*?[^_])?)_(?!_)/g, replacement: '$1<em>$2</em>'}`. Do you want to support empty highlights? `_` inside the highlighed texts? BTW, a simpler version will be `/(^|[^_])_([^_]*)_(?!_)/g`, but it will not support `_` inside those texts.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew ! Can you post that as an answer so I can mark it as correct? That worked great.

Comment: The second one?

Comment: I used the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
{regex: /(^|[^_])_(?!_)((?:[^]*?[^_])?)_(?!_)/g, replacement: '$1<em>$2</em>'}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vylenG/1/).

**Details**

- `(^|[^_])` - Group 1 (referenced to with `$1` from the replacement pattern, as this text should be put back into the result): start of string or any char other than `_`
- `_(?!_)` - a `_` not followed with `_`
- `((?:[^]*?[^_])?)` - Group 2 (referenced to with `$2` from the replacement pattern): any 0+ chars (`[^]*?`) as few as possible (`*?`), followed with a char other than `_`, zero or one time (optional)
- `_(?!_)` - a `_` not followed with `_`

Comment: Superuseful! You save my day! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

First, [Slack does not support markdown formatting](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting) (also noted [here](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/202288908-how-can-i-add-formatting-to-my-messages-)) but features a similiar more simple markup language:

Slack messages may be formatted using a simple markup language similar
to [Markdown](https://github.com/g105b/markdown-to-html). Supported formatting includes: `pre`, `code`,
*italic*, *bold*, and even ~strike~.;

Anyways, your best bet is using a popular markdown library like [Showdown](https://github.com/g105b/markdown-to-html) or if you really want to keep it simple you can use something like [this](https://github.com/g105b/markdown-to-html):

```js
;(function() { "use strict";

var
 output = "",

 BLOCK = "block",
 INLINE = "inline",

 /**
  * Used to attach MarkdownToHtml object to `window` in browser
  * context, or as an AMD module where appropriate.
  * @type {Object}
  */
 exports,

 /**
  * An array of parse rule descriptor objects. Each object has two keys;
  * pattern (the RegExp to match), and replace (the replacement string or
  * function to execute).
  * @type {Array}
  */
 parseMap = [
  {
   // <h1>
   // A line starting with 1-6 hashes.
   pattern: /(#{1,6})([^\n]+)/g,
   replace: "<h$L1>$2</h$L1>",
   type: BLOCK,
  },
  {
   // <p>
   // Any line surrounded by newlines that doesn't start with
   // an HTML tag, asterisk or numeric value with dot following.
   pattern: /\n(?!<\/?\w+>|\s?\*|\s?[0-9]+|>|\&gt;|-{5,})([^\n]+)/g,
   replace: "<p>$1</p>",
   type: BLOCK,
  },
  {
   // <blockquote>
   // A greater-than character preceding any characters.
   pattern: /\n(?:&gt;|\>)\W*(.*)/g,
   replace: "<blockquote><p>$1</p></blockquote>",
   type: BLOCK,
  },
  {
   // <ul>
   //
   pattern: /\n\s?\*\s*(.*)/g,
   replace: "<ul>\n\t<li>$1</li>\n</ul>",
   type: BLOCK,
  },
  {
   // <ol>
   //
   pattern: /\n\s?[0-9]+\.\s*(.*)/g,
   replace: "<ol>\n\t<li>$1</li>\n</ol>",
   type: BLOCK,
  },
  {
   // <strong>
   // Either two asterisks or two underscores, followed by any
   // characters, followed by the same two starting characters.
   pattern: /(\*\*|__)(.*?)\1/g,
   replace: "<strong>$2</strong>",
   type: INLINE,
  },
  {
   // <em>
   // Either one asterisk or one underscore, followed by any
   // characters, followed by the starting character.
   pattern: /(\*|_)(.*?)\1/g,
   replace: "<em>$2</em>",
   type: INLINE,
  },
  {
   // <a>
   // Not starting with an exclamation mark, square brackets
   // surrounding any characters, followed by parenthesis surrounding
   // any characters.
   pattern: /([^!])\[([^\[]+)\]\(([^\)]+)\)/g,
   replace: "$1<a href=\"$3\">$2</a>",
   type: INLINE,
  },
  {
   // <img>
   // Starting with an exclamation mark, then followed by square
   // brackets surrounding any characters, followed by parenthesis
   // surrounding any characters.
   pattern: /!\[([^\[]+)\]\(([^\)]+)\)/g,
   replace: "<img src=\"$2\" alt=\"$1\" />",
   type: INLINE,
  },
  {
   // <del>
   // Double tilde characters surrounding any characters.
   pattern: /\~\~(.*?)\~\~/g,
   replace: "<del>$1</del>",
   type: INLINE,
  },
  {
   // <code>
   //
   pattern: /`(.*?)`/g,
   replace: "<code>$1</code>",
   type: INLINE,
  },
  {
   // <hr>
   //
   pattern: /\n-{5,}\n/g,
   replace: "<hr />",
   type: BLOCK,
  },
 ],
$$;

/**
 * Self-executing function to handle exporting the parse function for
 * external use.
 */
(function go() {
 // Export AMD module if possible.
 if(typeof module !== "undefined"
 && typeof module.exports !== "undefined") {
  exports = module.exports;
 }
 // Otherwise check for browser context.
 else if(typeof window !== "undefined") {
  window.MarkdownToHtml = {};
  exports = window.MarkdownToHtml;
 }

 exports.parse = parse;
})();

/**
 * Parses a provided Markdown string into valid HTML.
 *
 * @param  {string} string Markdown input for transformation
 * @return {string}        Transformed HTML output
 */
function parse(string) {
 // Pad with newlines for compatibility.
 output = "\n" + string + "\n";

 parseMap.forEach(function(p) {
  // Replace all matches of provided RegExp pattern with either the
  // replacement string or callback function.
  output = output.replace(p.pattern, function() {
   // console.log(this, arguments);
   return replace.call(this, arguments, p.replace, p.type);
  });
 });

 // Perform any post-processing required.
 output = clean(output);
 // Trim for any spaces or newlines.
 output = output.trim();
 // Tidy up newlines to condense where more than 1 occurs back to back.
 output = output.replace(/[\n]{1,}/g, "\n");
 return output;
}

function replace(matchList, replacement, type) {
 var
  i,
 $$;

 for(i in matchList) {
  if(!matchList.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
   continue;
  }

  // Replace $n with the matching regexp group.
  replacement = replacement.split("$" + i).join(matchList[i]);
  // Replace $Ln with the matching regexp group's string length.
  replacement = replacement.split("$L" + i).join(matchList[i].length);
 }

 if(type === BLOCK) {
  replacement = replacement.trim() + "\n";
 }

 return replacement;
}

function clean(string) {
 var cleaningRuleArray = [
  {
   match: /<\/([uo]l)>\s*<\1>/g,
   replacement: "",
  },
  {
   match: /(<\/\w+>)<\/(blockquote)>\s*<\2>/g,
   replacement: "$1",
  },
 ];

 cleaningRuleArray.forEach(function(rule) {
  string = string.replace(rule.match, rule.replacement);
 });

 return string;
}

})();

var element = document.getElementById("example-markdown-content");
console.log(MarkdownToHtml.parse(element.innerHTML));
```

```html
<div id="example-markdown-content">
# Hello, Markdown!

Here is some example **formatting** in _Markdown_.
</div>
```

And if even this is too much you can trim it down easily since it is so simple. I guess this will save you a ton of time.